# Issue with mpi_gather

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I have written a simple code to familiarize myself with `mpi_gather`:

```
program main
    use mpi 
    implicit none
    integer :: myid, ierror, root_id, nprocs, ii
    logical :: boolean
    logical, dimension(:), allocatable :: all_booleans

    call mpi_init(ierror)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierror)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nprocs, ierror)

    if(myid==0) then
        print '(A9,I2)', "nprocs = ", nprocs
        print*, "************************************************************"
        print*, "From each processor"
    end if
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)

    boolean = .FALSE.
    root_id = 10
    if(myid==root_id) then
        boolean = .TRUE.
        allocate(all_booleans(0:nprocs-1))
    end if

    print '(A7,I2,A11,L2)', "myid = ", myid, " boolean = ", boolean
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)

    call mpi_gather(boolean, 1, mpi_logical, all_booleans, nprocs, mpi_logical, root_id,            &   
                & mpi_comm_world, ierror)

    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)
    if(myid==root_id) then
        print*, "******************************************************************"
        print *, "From the root processor, proc # : ", myid
        do ii=0,nprocs-1
            print '(A9,I2,A3,L2)', "processor ", ii, " = ", all_booleans(ii)
        end do
    end if
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)

    if(myid==root_id) then
        print*, "******************************************************************"
        print*, "From each processor"
    end if
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)
    print '(A7,I2,A11,L2)', "myid = ", myid, " boolean = ", boolean
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierror)

    call mpi_finalize(ierror)

end program main
```

I am using `mpiifort` from ifort version 14.0.2:

```
nprocs = 12
 ************************************************************
 From each processor
myid =  0 boolean =  F
myid =  1 boolean =  F
myid =  3 boolean =  F
myid =  4 boolean =  F
myid =  5 boolean =  F
myid =  6 boolean =  F
myid =  7 boolean =  F
myid =  8 boolean =  F
myid =  9 boolean =  F
myid = 10 boolean =  T
myid = 11 boolean =  F
myid =  2 boolean =  F
 ******************************************************************
 From the root processor, proc # :           10
processor 0 =  F
processor 1 =  T
processor 2 =  F
processor 3 =  T
processor 4 =  T
processor 5 =  T
processor 6 =  T
processor 7 =  T
processor 8 =  T
processor 9 =  T
processor10 =  T
processor11 =  T
 ******************************************************************
 From each processor
myid =  0 boolean =  F
myid =  1 boolean =  F
myid =  2 boolean =  F
myid =  3 boolean =  F
myid =  4 boolean =  F
myid =  5 boolean =  F
myid =  6 boolean =  F
myid =  7 boolean =  F
myid =  8 boolean =  F
myid =  9 boolean =  F
myid = 10 boolean =  T
myid = 11 boolean =  F
```

I set the variable `boolean` to `.TRUE.` only for the root processor (proc 10 here). I then gather all the `boolean` values into the array `all_booleans` to the root processor. When I output the values of `all_booleans`, I would expect to get `.FALSE.` for all indices except for `myid = 10`, which is not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `call mpi_gather(boolean, 1, mpi_logical, all_booleans, nprocs, mpi_logical, root_id, mpi_comm_world, ierror)` is wrong. It should read `call mpi_gather(boolean, 1, mpi_logical, all_booleans, 1, mpi_logical, root_id, mpi_comm_world, ierror)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the arguments to mpi_gather slightly wrong. From http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Gather.html for the recv_count it says

> recvcount
>       number of elements for any single receive (integer, significant only at root)

Note the word single. so if you change your call to

```
call mpi_gather(boolean, 1, mpi_logical, all_booleans, 1, mpi_logical, root_id,            &   
            & mpi_comm_world, ierror)
```

it works for me:

```
Wot now? mpif90 gath.f90
Wot now? mpirun -np 12 ./a.out
nprocs = 12
 ************************************************************
 From each processor
myid = 11 boolean =  F
myid =  3 boolean =  F
myid =  7 boolean =  F
myid =  8 boolean =  F
myid =  0 boolean =  F
myid =  4 boolean =  F
myid =  9 boolean =  F
myid = 10 boolean =  T
myid =  6 boolean =  F
myid =  2 boolean =  F
myid =  5 boolean =  F
myid =  1 boolean =  F
 ******************************************************************
 From the root processor, proc # :           10
processor 0 =  F
processor 1 =  F
processor 2 =  F
processor 3 =  F
processor 4 =  F
processor 5 =  F
processor 6 =  F
processor 7 =  F
processor 8 =  F
processor 9 =  F
processor10 =  T
processor11 =  F
 ******************************************************************
 From each processor
myid =  6 boolean =  F
myid = 11 boolean =  F
myid =  0 boolean =  F
myid =  2 boolean =  F
myid =  1 boolean =  F
myid =  3 boolean =  F
myid =  7 boolean =  F
myid =  9 boolean =  F
myid =  5 boolean =  F
myid = 10 boolean =  T
myid =  4 boolean =  F
myid =  8 boolean =  F
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit redundant? i.e. I expect `sendcount` and `recvcount` will always be the same

Comment: Data types need not be the same on both sides. Yes, madness lies down that route, but it is allowed ... Not so interesting for basic types, but when derived types are involved it might have its uses.

Comment: @solalito, the count and ordering of basic datatypes (also known as type signature) on both sides must match. But those basic datatypes could be grouped differently into e.g. derived datatypes.